# Fill out a column based on 2 other colums

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a macro that will allow me to automatically fill out the cells in a column based on 2 criteria, which are the county and the project type, both of which are their own column names. The column to be filled out will be called "Frequency Band", which will have a static range of 12 possible values.

For example, if the County is "Bergen" and the Project Type is "2", then the Frequency Band will be "800Mhz". If it is the same county (Bergen) but the project type is "3", then the frequency band will be "1900MHz".

I currently have the list of Frequency Bands listed in another worksheet (Just call it sheet 2, cells E2 – E13), so I imagine that the outline of the VBA code would look something like:

```
If County(A) = Lee AND Project Type(B) = 2 Then Frequency Band(C) = 800Mhz(E3)
Else if Project Type = 3 Then Frequency Band = 1900MHz
```

Etc., Etc. for each county

Since I’ve never coded in VBA before and have no idea of its syntax, I don't really know where to begin with a formula like this. Could anyone help get me started?

Comment: does this need to be in vba or would a function suffice? this would be quite easy to do with index, match in 2 dimension

Comment: I suppose a function would suffice but I'm a little confused as to how I would go about creating one that isn't incredibly long as there are over 100 counties that I'm dealing with, each having their own frequency band for each of the 4 projects that they have. This is a functionality that I plan on having to use many times in the future, which is why it was my first inclination to build a macro.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way it would work with a formula.

In cells G1:K6 there is a table with your stored data (could also be on another sheet)

Column A you put in a country, column B you put in a project type (would be good if you validated against your source data.

Column C is your lookup function

```
'=INDEX($H$2:$K$6,MATCH(A2,$G$2:$G$6,0),MATCH(B2,$H$1:$K$1,0))
```

Index takes 3 main inputs:

the array (H2:K6) which is the actual frequency values
a row number in this array, and a column number in the array

For the row number lookup your country in the list you have (g2:g6) and it will tell you it is the x number in the array which corresponds to the row in the index array

Same thing with the column and project type.

There is a ton of information on the net about index and match if you need more information.

Highlighing is to show which values the formula has picked in my three examples below.

[image]